# Why do "наддать" and "поддать" have the same meaning?

Tags: лексикон, выбор-слова, semantics, приставки

There are examples like *наддать пару* and *поддать пару* (not my favorite Russian words, but still they both exist).

They have the same meaning, at least that is what gramota.ru suggests: [наддать](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%ED%E0%E4%E4%E0%F2%FC), meaning 1 and [поддать](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%EF%EE%E4%E4%E0%F2%FC), meaning 3.

At the same time, prefixes *над-* and *под-* have exactly opposite meanings, at least as long as they refer to the position in space (*над-* stands for *above*, *под-* stands for *under*).

How come that adding prefixes with opposite meaning to the same stem results in the words with the same meaning?

Comment: Another interesting example - `поднажать` featuring both `на-` (though not `над-`) and `под-` prefixes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These prefixes were originally used in meaning "add to the top" and "add to the bottom", respectively.

The latter prefix later obtained metaphoric meaning "do a little" (literally, "do something in quality/quantity under the normal": *подкрась, подштопай, подлатай*). However, it's still used   in its original meaning in some words with distinct localization: *надставка / подставка* etc.

As the words in your example do not assume distinct localization, they are almost synonymous ("increase the effort"), but the latter word hints a little increase while the first one hints a significant increase.

Compare: *надбавь / подбавь*, *наддуй / поддуй*.

Comment: I agree and I like your explanation, with the only exception of two last examples, where you use a different prefix: "на-" instead of "над-".

Comment: Plus "add to the top" and "add to the bottom" are not probably the original meanings of the prefixes, but of the verbs.

Comment: @olga: `-дл-` is unstable in this position so *надложи / наложи* and *надлей / налей* have merged. But these words had been used in Russian with `над-` and Dahl mentions them.

Comment: I didn't realize that you were talking about diachrony, I meant that currently it is two different prefixes.

Comment: Compare: "насыпь-ка" and "надсыпь-ка"

Comment: @Olga: some words haven't merged yet. I changed my post to avoid confusion.

Comment: Maybe it is best to just remove these examples. I think that the difference and destiny of prefixes "на" and "над" is a different question.

Comment: And current dictionaries don't list "надложить" and "надлить".

Comment: @Olga: [okay.jpeg]